# Php to return value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**EDIT**: Check at the end of this for the solution

I am new to php, ajax and all other things :)

My question is: is there a way for a php file to return a value?

I have:

1. a file "loadImages.php" containing the script to get the paths to images from the database.
2. an image gallery where I want to load images via ajax.
3. a database containing the path to the images (/images/image1.jpg, /images/image2.jpg).
4. 4 categories of images.

What i'm trying to do is :

When clicking on a link (example, first category), I want to call via jquery's ajax(), loadImages.php with the category passed via POST (cat0, cat1, cat2, ...)

I want to return the value from this php file for example : `<img src="image/image1.jpg" />`, so via javascript, I can retrieve this string. Using only `return` in my php file returns `XMLHttpRequest` when i'm putting the `ajax()` function in a variable instead of the string `<img>`.

Is there a way to do it? Or maybe a better way, as I don't fully understand ajax.

Thank you! Sorry for my bad grammar.

Below is a more precise map of what i'm trying to do.

JavaScript:

```
var test = $.ajax({  
type: "POST",  
    url: "loadImages12.php",  
    data: "category=0",  
    complete: function() {  
        alert("COMPLETE");  
    },  
    error: function (){  
        alert("NOT LOADED");  
    }  
});
```

PHP (loadImages.php)

```
function createThumb() { 
        if(isset($_POST['category'])) {  
            $imageQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_pictures WHERE p_category = 0");
            $thumbHtml = '';

            while ($tempImageQueryFetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($imageQuery)){
                $thumbHtml .= '<a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="ressources/images/' . $tempImageQueryFetch["p_fileName"] . 'Small.jpg" /></a>';
            }

        return $thumbHtml;
        }
        else {
            $noCategory = "NO CATEGORY TEST";
            return $noCategory ;
        }
    }

    createThumb();
```

**SOLVED**

- Php File

  function createThumb(){
  //Mysql request
  $someVar =  //Result of request
  return $someVar
  }

  echo createThumb()
- Javascript

  $("#someDiv").load("loadImages.php", {category:0});

Comment: I'm new to AJAX, too. I use $.post to send XHRs and in my PHP file, I "echo" the response (I don't use functions). Try using the $.post method.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did! The load function is easier to use finally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An AJAX request to PHP is exactly the same as a normal request for a website. You request data from `example.com/foo/bar` and in return you receive **text**. The `return` statement of PHP has nothing to do with what's returned to the client. Only things you `echo` or otherwise *output* will be received by the client. That's the same for normal pages and AJAX requests.

So, to "return" `<img src="image/image1.jpg" />` to your Javascript AJAX call, `echo` that string in PHP.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I used : $("someDiv").load("loadImages", {category:0}) instead. And I `echo`(ed) the function in my php file.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use the php file that you already have (loadImages.php) just echo the result of the function:

```
echo createThumb();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make the php script to return the path to thumbnail.

and then do something like this in js

```
somediv.html('<a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="">');
```

and just use the path returned by the php file for the img src ..